# How can I add a repository to conda

Tags: python, repository, conda

I am trying to install python-qutip to run on IPython notebook, which I have configured to run using the conda path variables . [Qutip](http://qutip.org/docs/latest/) is an extremely popular (and useful) open-source package to simulate open quantum suystems.

With

```
    conda install python-qutip
```

or

```
    pip-install python-qutip
```

I get `Error: No packages found matching: python-qutip` (as expected). Same thing with

```
    pip install python-qutip
```

As a quick 'n dirty solution, Is there some way to add the `jrjohansson/qutip-releases` repository to my conda library?

Alternatively, is it possible to install manually as in: `sudo python setup.py install` and add the installation directory to the conda path?

Answer (score 4):

If you search anaconda.com you find the following:

```
Using binstar api site https://api.anaconda.org
Name:    qutip
Summary: QuTiP: The Quantum Toolbox in Python
Access:  public
Package Types:  conda
Versions:
   + 3.0.1
   + 3.0.0
   + 3.1.0

To install this package with conda run:
     conda install --channel https://conda.anaconda.org/jrjohansson qutip
```

The last line works for me (OpenSuse 13.1, miniconda).

Answer (score 4):

I figure you've probably solved this at this point but for any wandering search-engine travelers:

In addition to specifying a channel for a singular install, [anaconda's docs](https://conda.io/docs/user-guide/tasks/manage-channels.html) give this method for adding a channel to your user's conda config(with conda>=4.1):

```
conda config --add channels new_channel
```

You can also see the channels you currently have added in `~/.condarc` or by running `conda config --show`

For this particular case, you might do something like:

```
conda config --add channels jrjohansson
conda install python-qutip
```

If you're installing packages from a particular channel frequently(e.g. from conda-forge), this can be pretty useful.

Hope it helps :)

Answer (score 2):

I think the easiest way to install qutip is the following

```
pip install qutip
```

This worked for me.

(It could be `pip3 install qutip` instead.)

Comment: Thanks. I have qutip installed already but it requires conda to be disabled in the python path. My question was how to install qutip if I want to stick to the conda path variables. Truth of the matter is most of the libraries included in conda are not really useful in conjunction with qutip, so that commenting out the part of my PYTHONPATH which refers to conda is a workable poor man's solution. I enable it back only when I need it.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have conda-build installed, you can try building the conda recipe (currently on a fork):

```
git clone https://github.com/jrjohansson/conda-recipes.git
cd conda-recipes
conda build qutip
conda install --use-local qutip
```

Didn't work for my env (ubuntu saucy) but I didn't try too hard. Maybe it will work for you!

Comment: Thanks @mattexx. I have temporarily stopped using `qutip` and `conda` on my system (shifting priorities ;-) ), but I'll try your suggestion next time the need arises.